# Позиционирование блоков при 100% высоте

Tags: css

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть css и html:

Как сделать, чтобы в этом случае при маленькой высоте экрана блок footer не перекрывал другие блоки? http://jsfiddle.net/04h63539/

```css
body {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border: 0;
  zoom: 1;
  width: auto;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 550px;
  border-left: 8px solid red;
  border-right: 8px solid red;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
}
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.us {
  position: relative;
  width: 170px;
  height: 170px;
  background-color: #DBDBDB;
  display: table-cell;
}
.footer {
  display: block;
  background-color: #515151;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <div class="us"></div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Цвета по хекс-кодам угадывать? Сделай что-нибудь более понятное и сократи пример.

Comment: @Qwertiy http://jsfiddle.net/0th4a92u/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/04h63539/2/
http://jsfiddle.net/0th4a92u/1/ И внешний div в разметке лишний.

```
body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-bottom: 80px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Футер прикрепить к низу страницу можно через flex-box

```css
body {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border: 0;
  zoom: 1;
  width: auto;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 550px;
  border-left: 8px solid red;
  border-right: 8px solid red;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
}
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.content {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1;
          flex: 1;
}
.us {
  width: 170px;
  height: 170px;
  background-color: #DBDBDB;
}
.footer {
  background-color: #515151;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="us"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Можно, но зачем? Зачем то, что без проблем делается старыми способами, делать новыми и наживать себе баги? У него же футер фиксированной высоты.

Comment: неплохо узнать что эту задачу можно решить другими способами.
но вы правы, в данном случае бордер бокс и паддинг самое короткое и подходящее решение.

Comment: Префиксы сейчас не очень нужны. Кстати, а зачем `-webkit-box-direction: normal;` - он чем-то особенный?

Comment: прогнал CSS через [автопрефиксер](https://autoprefixer.github.io/ru/)

Comment: Спасибо! А какой из вариатнов более кроссбраузерный?